# PDF.js garbage rendering issue

Tags: javascript, android, html, pdf, pdf.js

I am using PDF.js to download and display pdf files in the WebView of my Android app.

I use this implementation: https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js

So far, everything was fine. The "next page" and "previous page" was handled by two buttons in the html file which is implemented like this:

```
<div>
<button id="prev" onclick="goPrevious()" class="button">Previous</button>
<button id="next" onclick="goNext()" class="button">Next</button>
&nbsp; &nbsp;
<span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>
```

I wanted to remove these buttons from HTML and rather use two buttons on the actionbar to implement page navigation.
I call these buttons like this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {


    case R.id.action_next:

        WebView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:goNext()");

    case R.id.action_previous:

        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:goPrevious()");
     }
```

This causes the page to change on clicking the next/previous buttons but instead of rendering a fresh page, the next page is overlapped with the previous one & everything looks garbage.

Why is this happening ? Both the implementations call the same javascript function, yet one works perfectly, other causes this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of Android-pdf.js not properly implemented onPrevious and onNext buttons at https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js/blob/master/assets/pdfviewer/customview.js.

Here is code from the pdf.js examples http://jsbin.com/pdfjs-prevnext-v2/6865/edit#html,live (which is listed on the project's main page at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. Clicking the buttons does not change the page. The javascript console shows the following error: 

 `Warning: Unhandled rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property     'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined     at Object.onResolve (http://localhost/MySite/customview.js:45:27)     at Object.runHandlers (http://localhost/MySite/pdf.worker.js:795:35)`

This has something to do with compatibility.js being included

Comment: add ancient 0.8 version of PDF.js is used -- current version 1.0.700

Comment: No. I did update all the files in my project (the repo is not updated yet). Still it does not work.